# How to fix PDF preview in LyX for Mac?

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX on Mac but whenever I preview the pdf for the document the pdf cuts off after two pages and the text ignores the bottom margin of the second page as shown in the screenshot. How do I fix this?

Edit: The LaTex code is pasted below (with most of the sections and subsections omitted).

\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{LC HL Maths Syllabus }
\maketitle

\section{Statistics and Probability}

.
.
.

\subsubsection{Integrals of Various Functions}
\end{document}

[image: screenshot of pdf preview of document]

Comment: I've never seen this. If you go to Tools > Preferences > File Handling > File Formats, then select the PDF format in the dropdown, e.g., `PDF (pdflatex)`, what is listed under "Viewer" ? You might consider trying the options under "Viewer". To do that, select a different one and choose "OK". I think the default PDF viewer for macOS is "Skim" ?

Comment: I think this behavior is caused by all the adjacent sectioning titles with no text between them, and not the fault of the PDF viewer. Can you post the LaTeX code produced by this file?

Comment: The "Viewer" is set to "Custom" as "auto" and the only other option is "None". I have posted the LaTex code in the edit.

Comment: Insert some words after the sections  to fix it.